# Regexp only allow Chinese Characters not allow Alphabetic Characters

Tags: javascript

I need to allow only allow Chinese Characters If input English characters not allow it.

**Example :**

```js
var inputEng ="TEST";
let reqChinese= /^[\u3000\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\u9FFF]$/  only matching Chinese 
console.log(reqChinese.test(inputEng)); //but here getting true
```

**Expected out-put: false //console result**

- Note :If input Chinese Character match "true" or else "false".

Comment: Could you show expected and actual output?

Comment: I googled this http://flyingsky.github.io/2018/01/26/javascript-detect-chinese-japanese/ Since I don't know Chinese I can't validate it.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov Need to console If match Chinese Characters true or else false.